# Chrome Extension: Adding click event handler to button not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to add a click event handler on to a button in my chrome extension. No matter what I try, the function "save" will not activate on button click. The `index.html` file looks like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        <button id="save-button">Save</button>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the code to add the event handler on to the button looks like this:

```js
function save() {
  console.log('SAVE TEST')
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const saveButton = document.getElementById('save-button')
  saveButton.addEventListener('click', save);
});
```

I have confirmed that the `saveButton.addEventListener` is being called. I've looked everywhere online and it seems like I am doing things right, but I must be messing up somewhere that I just cannot figure out...

Comment: When I try on my local. It works. 
It logs out when I click.

Comment: May be try removing `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {` 
As you are calling script tag at the end this line may not be necessary